# Why does my GameObject returns back to a certain z-position when Joystick is let go?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a small project in unity. It's a top down game which has a character that is controlled by a joystick. When I run the game, my character starts -90 on the z-position which supposed to be at 0. But when I move the joystick to the direction I wanted it to run it works fine, meaning it's facing the direction where it's running to. However, if I let go of the joystick, the character snaps back to -90 in z-position, which I am trying to figure why it does that and prevent it from happening.

I have looked for tutorial videos and some post in here but none has answered my issue. I also tried removing the "-90f" on my Mathf.Atan2 formula but when I did, it rotates 90 in z-position less. Meaning, when I direct the joystick straight down, the character rotates facing right.

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static PlayerController instance;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Joystick joystick;

    private float moveSpeed = 2.5f;
    Vector2 movement;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = joystick.Horizontal;
        movement.y = joystick.Vertical;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(movement.y, movement.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle));
    }
```

I expect to  have my character to start on 0 in z-position when the game start and also have the character stay and face the direction of the joystick before it was let go instead of rotating back to -90 in z-position.

Comment: A couple of images showing current and desired character motion (with axes) would help us.  Also, are you using 2D or 3D physics?

Comment: I believe your problem with the snap back is that you are checking and updating the angle based on the current movement. This works when you are moving, but when you stop `Mathf.Atan2(0,0) * Mathf.Rad2Deg-90f;` is calculated. and then rotated towards.

Comment: It would be best to only update the angle if movement or position has changed since the last update.

Comment: @Immersive Im using 2D physics

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I have not thought of that, I will try your recommendation and get back if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TheLazyScripter, I was able to re-code my script and make my character do what I needed it to do. I simply overlooked that it was on FixedUpdate and so it will continue calling it even when I stop the joystick. I'm still a noob at programming and I've been learning for the past week, I have no rest. Anyways, here's what I did with my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (joystick.Horizontal >= .1f || joystick.Horizontal <= -.1f)
        {
            movement.x = joystick.Horizontal;
            MoveCharacter();
        }
        else
        {
            movement.x = 0f;
            angle = 0f;
        }

        if (joystick.Vertical >= .1f || joystick.Vertical <= -.1f)
        {
            movement.y = joystick.Vertical;
            MoveCharacter();
        }
        else
        {
            movement.y = 0f;
            angle = 0f;
        }
    }

    void MoveCharacter()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(movement.y, movement.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle));
    }
```

Hopefully this may help someone that might have the same problem. I doubt anyone would have the same problem but I hope it helps. :D